# jQuery swipe to scroll up/down

Tags: jquery, scroll, swipe

I want to make a tablet website, which scroll down between `<section>` on swipe event.

I'm a jQuery neewbie. I've tried some libraries but nothing worked for me.

I just need up/down and no horizontal scrolling.

i.e. have the user swipe and the page scrolls down a pagefull

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to 2 things: (a) is a way to 'listen' to the swipe events and (b) a way to do the pagination itself in response to the event. There might even be a solution that does both. I don't have a suggestion off the top of my head right now.

Note: below is my original answer, after getting more details it's not what the OP was looking for.

Do you need to scroll the entire page? or just a section (for example a DIV). Consider if css attribute `overflow: scroll` on your `DIV` with a set height is enough.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/Am3jE/1/)

HTML:

```
<p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
<div id="ScrollArea">This should <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>scroll</div>
<p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
```

CSS:

```
#ScrollArea {border: 1px dotted red; height: 6ex; overflow: scroll}
```

Comment: i want to use it for a tablet so the user doesn't need to scroll, he can swipe down to another div, section

Comment: @CosminStan A tablet browser should let the user scroll normally with their fingers. Do you want to have pagination? i.e. have the user swipe and the page scrolls a pagefull?

Comment: Ahh, in that case what I posted won't help you. I'm not sure how to do what you need, update your question with the additional details someone will surely know. There's probably already a plugin or library that does this.

Comment: no that many with the up/down swipe.. and i don't know how to make the others work, aniway thanks!